# python turn u' into "

Tags: python, json

I am making some lists of string from data I get from the web, and I eventually want to turn it into JSON, and I am getting and error that I need double quotes on the JSON, how could I turn the string I get back from the web to double quotes instead of `u'`?

here is sample input

```
my_string = "test"
my_array = [u'hi', u'hello']
```

and sample output

```
final = {"test":["hi", "hello"]}
```

Writing file like this

```
my_file = open("test.json", "w")
my_file.write(str(final))
my_file.close()
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the data and where in your code are you experiencing this problem?

Comment: @metatoaster the data is a list of string, that I get from the web using `beautiful soup` , and then I am eventually making a JSON file out of the lists

Comment: Can you add a sample input and the desired output

Comment: @RahulGupta see above, and then I want to write the sample output to a json file which I will post above

Comment: Your problem likely has nothing to do with the unicode strings you're blaming it on, but without a clear problem statement it's difficult to diagnose. What's the code that's throwing the error, and what's the error you're getting *exactly*?

Comment: In....other words, you want to turn unicode strings into normal strings.

Comment: @AdamSmith maxymoo got it, I didn't know you have to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `json` library to convert Python `dict` objets to json:

```
import json
print(json.dumps({my_string:my_array}))

'{"test": ["hi", "hello"]}'
```

Comment: I think you're probably right, but it's tough to know without more info

Comment: `DoubleQuotesError: must use double quotes`

Comment: @maxymoo you probably want to update your question with the code you have, how it behaves, under what conditions it triggers the error you're seeing and how to reproduce it. the general advice of 'use a json library' is right.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str):

```
In [1]: a = u'hi'

In [2]: a
Out[2]: u'hi'

In [3]: str(a)
Out[3]: 'hi'
```